# CSS свойство которое устанавливает длительность эффекта

Tags: css

Есть ли CSS свойство которое устанавливает длительность другого CSS свойства,   (не переход, от одного состояния в другое, а именно длительность) например при ошибочной валидации красная рамка должна гореть 5 секунд

```
<style>
input:valid:not([type="submit"]) {
border:2px solid green;
}
.a:invalid:not(:focus):not(:placeholder-shown) {
border:2px solid red;
transition:2s;
}
</style>

<form onsubmit="go(); return false">
<span>введите имя</span><input class="a" placeholder=" " id="name" 
type="text" required  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]{5,15}"><br>
<span>введите фамилию</span><input class="a" placeholder=" " id="surname" 
type="text" required  pattern="[А-Яа-яЁё]{5,15}"><br>
<input type="submit" value="сохранить" >
</form>
```

Comment: Почему не решить эту проблему плавным переходом? Если случается триггер события рамка переходит в псевдокласс, который в свою очередь имеет обратный эффект, который применяется спустя 5 секунд.

Comment: и как рамку перевести в псевдокласс?  объясните пожалуйста, ибо я таких  вещей даже в по миме  не знаю

Comment: `.a:invalid {transition:color  .5s, color .5s;}` Вроде бы так можно, но я не уверен, а времени проверить сейчас нет. В общем, можно задать несколько переходов, я думаю, это то, что вам нужно.
Подробнее, почитайте [здесь](https://html5book.ru/css3-transition/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разрешить вашу проблему можно использованием CSS анимаций. Подробнее:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: спасибо за ответ, спасибо за ссылку, в ней я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Если надо задавать именно длительность перехода, то надо использовать

```
transition-duration: 2s;
```

Если одновременно используется несколько анимаций, требующих различные длительности, то их нужно перечислять через запятую.